# Is “yet” and “ever” interchangeable in “the most pivotal contest yet / ever”

Tags: word-usage

Today’s (February 7) Time magazine carries an article titled, ”Republicans ready for eighth debate,” which starts with the paragraph, “Republican presidential candidates will face off in New Hampshire Saturday night in **the most pivotal contest yet**, just 72 hours before polls close in New Hampshire.”

Though this may sound a primitive question, is “yet” in “the most pivotal contest yet” interchangeable with “ever.” I consulted with an English dictionary at hand, but don't get a clear idea of the difference of the usage of "-(e.g. newest) yet" and "- ever." Are they exactly same in the meaning? If not, what’s the difference?

Comment: As @JohnClifford says *ever* is a greater word than *yet*. In the context of your question the meanings are quite different: **...the most pivotal contest yet**, means the most pivotal contest during *this* election, whereas **...the most pivotal contest ever**, means the most pivotal contest of *any* election throughout history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pivotal differences: "yet" has the primary meaning of

> up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then.

while "ever" has the primary meaning of

> at any time.

"the most pivotal contest yet" means the most pivotal that has occurred up until the present, but has a kind of implicit implication that more will occur in the future.

"the most pivotal contest ever" while it doesn't necessarily *eliminate* the possibility of a better one coming along later, has a much stronger implication that this is the most pivotal there has ever been and possibly ever will be.

In this exact context, I think using "ever" would be ill-advised as presidential contests happen frequently and there's a pretty good chance there will be another one just as pivotal if not more so. It just doesn't sit right.